# MySQL some views are not created when restoring from dump

Tags: mysql

I faced strange issue when restoring MySQL database from dump. Dump contains only tables structure without any data. There are tables and views.

If I run following from mysql console everything works fine

`mysql> source path/to/dump.sql`

But if I execute following:

`mysql --user=root --password=PASSWORD dbName < /path/to/file.sql`

Then several views are not being created. The same is true when I execute SQL file via `php` migration.

I need to run it automatically, so how can I get it working without `mysql` prompt?

**[Update 1]**

Dump was done with `mysqldump` from local database and now I'm trying to restore it from on the same `mysql` instance with the same `root` user.

All views look the same, but for some reasons they all are created when I import sql file from `mysql` prompt via `source` command. Otherwise only some views are created.

This is how each view looks:

```
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `my_view`*/;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_client          = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_results         = @@character_set_results */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_col_connection     = @@collation_connection */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = utf8 */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = utf8_general_ci */;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50001 VIEW `my_view` AS select `a`.`order_id` AS 
    `order_id`,`a`.`client_id` AS `client_id`,`b`.`device_platform` AS 
    `device_platform` .... from (`tbl_1` `a` left join `tbl_2` `b` 
    on((`a`.`client_id` = `b`.`client_id`))) where (`b`.`status` = 
   'active') */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;
```

Comment: Without seeing the SQL in the dump or seeing what options you used when creating it, there's not much we can do. Normally, views are recreated just fine. Perhaps there's a problem with your schema such that the views are referencing tables/columns that no longer exist (and thus the view cannot be created).

Comment: What tool was used to take the dump?  And what permissions did you have when taking the dump?  At least `SHOW VIEWS` is needed.

Comment: Updated question with example of SQL from the dump